# GPL - Does "internal use" apply for a public gameserver?

Tags: gpl, derivative-works

While reading through the GPL FAQ I found some relevant points to the question, however it is still unclear to me if this fully applies to a public gameserver.

I'll try to keep it short:

There is a gameserver A, fully available, including source code, published under the GPL.
There is a modified gameserver B, based on server A, not available as binary nor as source code. Maintainer of modified server B however does grant access to his modified server as a public service, i.e. to play the game, obviously.

From the GPL FAQ:

> **Does the GPL require that source code of modified versions be posted to the public?**
>
> The GPL does not require you to release your modified version, or any part of it. You are free to make modifications and use them privately, without ever releasing them. This applies to organizations (including companies), too; an organization can make a modified version and use it internally without ever releasing it outside the organization.
>
> But if you release the modified version to the public in some way, the GPL requires you to make the modified source code available to the program's users, under the GPL.
>
> Thus, the GPL gives permission to release the modified program in certain ways, and not in other ways; but the decision of whether to release it is up to you.

So to me it is not obvious what does apply here.

On one hand the "**modified version**" is clearly "**release**[d] **to the public in some way**" to the "**program's users**" (i.e. the players),
however on the other hand it is kept as an "**internal**" tool.

As I understand it, "internal" in this context suggests, that the software can be used without publishing, if the public has nothing to do with the software itself.

But the server, and the providing of the public service in this case is not just part of something unrelated but the very core and reason of existance of the whole public project.

Comment: Read also about the [AGPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affero_General_Public_License), and ask your lawyer. But the simplest way is to comply with the spirit of GPL and publish under GPL license your modified program source code.

Answer (score 20):

> On one hand the "modified version" is clearly "release[d] to the public in some way" to the "program's users" (i.e. the players), however on the other hand it is kept as an "internal" tool.

This is not correct.

Exposing the server, public or private, is not considered distribution according to the terms of the GPL and so the requirements of the GPL do not come into play. The only way it would, for a GPL licensed server would be if players downloaded the server software and ran instances of the server on their own computers.

There is a similar license, the GNU Affero General Public License, which mandates exposing the software via Remote Network Interaction to require the recipient of the software to also provide the source to the users. The way you think the GPL works, is basically how the AGPL works instead.

This is also covered in the GNU FAQ: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#UnreleasedMods

Comment: Again, I do not ask for any upcoming project and going with AGPL therefore is not an option.

These mentioned projects exist and the aformentioned server A was published under GPL.

The FAQ you quote suggests that in this case it IS indeed legitimate to ask for the source code?

Comment: The point UnreleasedMods that you've linked to explicitly says that under GPL it would indeed be legitimate to ask for the projects source code. So this is exactly what I said. How come you link that and at the same time suggest it wasn't correct? The FAQ point says to avoid such constellation one should use AGPL. But this was not a hypothetical question.
Both, server A and server B of the original question already exist, and Server A was released under GPL, not under AGPL. From your link:
"putting the program on a server machine for the public to talk to is hardly “private” use"

Comment: @norad I think the point is that the language of the GPL is unclear about this, so it may be legitimate to require the source, but it's not clear you *must*. On the other hand, the AGPL *is* clear on the matter. Since in your scenario you don't get to choose the license, I'd say the answer is "you cannot be sure whether you're required to release the source code; all the GPL says it that it would make sense to do it, but it doesn't mandate it in clear & unambiguous words". After all, if the GPL was clear enough, why would the AGPL be needed?

Comment: @norad: it is legitimate to ask for the source with regards to the ideals of the FSF, not according to the terms of the GPL. Remote Network Interaction is not considered distribution (or conveying in GPLv3 terms). Read the GPL yourself, it's not that long and it will be clear.

Comment: @AndresF: The GPL is not unclear about this, it very specifically defines what distribution is. The AGPL didn't get created because the GPL was unclear, it was created in response to a new model of what a user of a software was.

Comment: @whatisname Maybe you're right. So when the FAQ says `"However, putting the program on a server machine for the public to talk to is hardly “private” use, so it would be legitimate to require release of the source code in that special case"`, is this NOT covered by the GPL? (i.e. even though this is a form of distribution, it's not something the GPL v2 considered). The wording *of the FAQ*, taken in isolation, is unclear to me in this case. Is this something that the GPL didn't cover, and hence the AGPL was required?

Comment: @whatsisname I can see the "mere network interaction is not distribution" part in the GPL. But "private use" still contradicts a public server/service. If I grant access to non-server software, but only by glueing it to a remote shell accessible through "mere network interaction" - this would then still not be distribution? Even if I understand that the problem araises by not having server-client models in mind, it still occurs to me the refusing of publishing is more a loophole than a legitimate base.

Comment: this answer is just plain correct.

Comment: Using this logic, I could charge to provide a web version of any GPL derived software and never release any of the code for it. Further, I could make any GPL software run on a server and then create and charge users to download and use a special client application which does nothing more than act as an I/O for the user to access that server, and I'd never need to release any of the source.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare whether you use this logic or not, it is nevertheless true. It sounds like you don't like that; that's fine, but it is still true. The AGPL was created specifically to close that preceived gap.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare, true. But GPLv2 was written before Internet was even science fiction (software was distributed via tape!), no wonder it doesn't consider this case.

Comment: @vonbrand - Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe GPLv2 was written in 1991. The first web browser, WorldWideWeb, was created in 1990. ARPANET was created in the late 60s. The Internet was a part of science fiction since the 1800s. GPLv2 should have been very aware of the Internet.

Comment: @curiousdannii The GPL license restrictions only come into affect when *you distribute a modified copy of the code*. If you do not distribute your modifications, or if the copies you distribute are unmodified, then you are not required to comply with any GPL restrictions. Under the GPL license' definition of "distribute" running a publicly accessible server is not considered "distribution".

Comment: For example, the Linux kernel is GPL licensed. You are allowed to modify the kernel and install it on your own servers without making those modifications public. Your Linux server can be publicly accessible by millions of people every day, with people "using" your server but that's not a distribution. If you share your modifications with somebody so they can use it on their server, then you're required to do so under GPL. This has been well established for decades and is an intentional part of the license. If you don't like it, then don't release your code under GPL.

Comment: @curiousdannii you asked someone to go into more detail and they didn't do it, so I did

Comment: @Abhi D'oh I must have read these comments a dozen times, and each time I thought bmargulies said it was "plain *in*correct"! Brain fail.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: the first part, yes. The second part, no. The reason being is that since your special client software is designed to interface specifically and solely with the GPL software, then the whole thing is effectively a single program so the GPL would come into play. Crossing a network barrier doesn't mean it's automatically two seperate works. See: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#GPLInProprietarySystem

Comment: @AbhiBeckert: you are on the hook for providing source even if you distribute unmodified copies of GPL software.

Comment: @whatsisname no, you just have to tell someone where they can get the source if they ask for it. Assuming you leave the binary *unmodified* it will already contain instructions where to download the source - the license requires the person you got the binary off to do that, so in practical terms you can ignore the license so long as you don't make changes. Or at least that's how GPLv2 works, I'm not as familiar with GPLv3 - never distributed code under v3 - I just had a look and it replaces a single paragraph with a whole section of legalese... yuck!

Comment: I don't see what could be ambiguous in that FAQ answer, when you read it from start to finish. "Would be legitimate to require" in the context of that FAQ answer clearly means **from the standpoint of someone writing or choosing a license.**